# for loops in coffee script

Tags: javascript, json, coffeescript

I'm trying my hand at CoffeeScript at the moment by converting a vanilla JavaScript feed parser I built to query Instagram. I've been hitting my head against the wall trying to get the logic to work inside of a for loop, I can get a simple for loop to work as per the 100's of examples on the web but I've yet to get one with more code inside the for loop. Am I approaching this completely wrong? The argument "results" I pass into the function is a JSON object.

```
_feed: (results) ->
    images = results.length
    for img in images
      a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = results.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url;
      img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = results.data[i].images.low_resolution.url;
      a.appendChild(img);
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(a);
```

I keep getting errors saying unexpected outdent. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like this instead:

```
_feed: (results) ->
    for result in results.data
        a = document.createElement 'a'
        a.href = result.images.standard_resolution.url

        img = document.createElement 'img'
        img.src = result.images.low_resolution.url

        a.appendChild img
        document.body.appendChild a
```

The main difference is that the `for` loop iterates over each item in `results.data`. You still had `results.data[i]` in your loop, which isn't really necessary if you're iterating item-by-item.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for..of` if `results.data` is an object?

Comment: @elclanrs: Isn't `results.data` an array? I thought it was an array.

Comment: thats great thanks for that. I did say an object yes but that code works - should it? Also, why if I delete all of the code below the for loop it gives me an error when compiling? Obviously I want the code below but I'm just trying to understand whats happening. Cheers

Comment: @JamesBillings: Try it out in the [online CS compiler](http://coffeescript.org/#try:for%20result%20in%20results.data%0A%20%20%20%20a%20%3D%20document.createElement%20'a'%0A%20%20%20%20a.href%20%3D%20result.images.standard_resolution.url%0A%0A%20%20%20%20img%20%3D%20document.createElement%20'img'%0A%20%20%20%20img.src%20%3D%20result.images.low_resolution.url%0A%0A%20%20%20%20a.appendChild%20img%0A%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild%20a). The `for...in` loop in CS is the way you iterate over an array, but the `for...of` loop is like the `for...in` in normal JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using an editor that uses soft tabs (spaces) instead of hard tabs; and check that all the lines are indented as you expect: two spaces for the first two lines, four spaces for the other lines; etc. Otherwise, you will definitely get those errors mixing tabs and spaces.

**I also see that there is a random backtick at the very end of your code; is that in the actual code or did you just copy it here?**

Also, start ignoring semicolons; you don't need them :)